# Left menu is a jsp page and to load the values from database rl is

Tags: struts2

I am using struts2+tiles framework. I have leftmenu.jsp where in which I want to display the items from the database as and when the site is up.

thanks

swapna

Answer (score 0):

I think U can do this in by using a list "itemlist" in your action class which gets value from database in the form of list what you want to display in your items and then you can use the same itemlist in your jsp to iterate by using

```
<struts:iterator value="itemlist"> 
<struts:property value="listField">
</struts:iterator>
```

and get the values in jsp.